# TColorBox > NoneColorColor (not used?)

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am using `TColorBox`, which has a [`NoneColorColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TColorBox.NoneColorColor) property:

> Specifies the color displayed in the color box for clNone.

I thought it was used to show the `TColorBox` when it is set to `clNone`.

However, when I set `Selected` to `clNone`, the color is set to that of the `Color` property, not to `NoneColorColor`.

```
void __fastcall TForm2::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    ColorBox1->NoneColorColor = clGreen;
    ColorBox1->Selected = clNone;
}
```

The above code makes the `TColorBox` white (set in `Color`), not Green.

Is the `NoneColorColor` used?

Comment: Did you miss *This property only affects the color box if the Style property includes cbSystemColors and cbIncludeNone.*, by chance?

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you very much. Actually, I missed the sentence. It worked now.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you for editing my question. By the way, you deleted my Environment "10.2 Tokyo", which may help readers to solve their problems sometimes (related to the build version).

Comment: The [tag:c++builder-10.2-tokyo] tag at the bottom left of your question tells people what environment you're using, so Remy's removal was appropriate. Including the tag information in the text is redundant.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand what you are doing. But my style is to include Environmental text even tag is specified. I know some people think that is redundant but... I will think about it for my future question.